# Integrate $\int \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sin^2 x}\,\mathrm dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble evaluating the integral

$$\int \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sin^2 x}\,\mathrm dx.$$

I tried $u$-substitution and integration by parts but they didn't work.

Comment: integration by parts works, pick f = ln term, so that f' can be found. Then g' is csc²x of which g is a known anti derivative

Comment: You r confusing me can u explain me more please?

Comment: Follow the technique given in the comment by imranfat.

Comment: I don't understand what he meant.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a start. using integration by parts,

> $$ \int u dv = u v - \int v du .$$

Let

$$ u=\ln(\sin(x)) \implies u'=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\cot(x),\quad v=\int \frac{dx}{\sin^2 x}=-\cot(x). $$

Can you finish it now?

Comment: Ok I think I got it, thank you very much!

Comment: @MorganStone: you are very welcome.